# The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I found this error

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint

while run following code,

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
        ForcePathStyle = true,
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
        SignatureVersion = "v4"
     };           

// Set to a bucket you create   
// Create S3 service client.          
using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(kAWSAccessKeyId, kAWSSecretAccessKey, S3Config))
{
    // Setup request for putting an object in S3. 
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
       {
           BucketName = kBucketName,
           Key = "Contents/SampleData",
            ContentBody = "Sample Content"
        };

        // Make service call and get back the response.    
        PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
}
```

I have changed all region but in every region it showing same error

Comment: There's only one correct region for each bucket, so there is no reason to try them all.  Identify the correct region for the bucket using the AWS console, and set it with `RegionEndpoint`, then remove `serviceURL, which is redundant at best.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ,Thanks for your time. On aws console its showing "https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/imagetest/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview". But when I am accessing any object in S3, it is showing  url having different region "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/imagetest/imagetest.com/image/a245_1.jpg" . One more thing eu-west-2 is not available in aws c# sdk. I am totally stucked.

Comment: The region shown in the address bar of the browser while viewing the console isn't likely relevant -- that's usually just the region of the internal system that's serving up the console UI for your browser session.  The other URL -- unless you sanitized it -- implies that your bucket's name is "imagetest" which is highly unlikely.  The bucket namespace is global so the odds that you have a bucket with such a common name are low.  Also, that bucket has been deactivated, as you can see [here](https://imagetest.s3.amazonaws.com).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong url. console url is https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/gowherewolf/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview and file url is https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gowherewolf/gowherewolf.com/image/2017/05/18/591d29518a245_1.jpg

Comment: Your bucket is indeed in eu-west-2 (London).  The endpoint was apparently added to the SDK in [version 3.3.31.0 on 2016-12-15](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/SDK.CHANGELOG.md#33310-2016-12-15-2320-utc).

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael-sqlbot